# Mapping signalr users to connections using SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I read this [topic](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#database) about mapping SignalR users to connections. Briefly, the topic explain four methods of mapping and I want to use the forth method (Permanent, external storage). The method uses a SQL Server database to store the `ConnectionId` when the client is connected (when `OnConnected` method is fired) and when the client closes the browser (when `OnDisconnected` method is fired) it just make the `ConnectionId` not valid.

Here is the code for database:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
}

public class Connection
{
    public string ConnectionID { get; set; }
    public string UserAgent { get; set; }
    public bool Connected { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the code in the hub class:

```
[Authorize]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void SendChatMessage(string who, string message)
    {
        var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        using (var db = new UserContext())
        {
            var user = db.Users.Find(who);
            if (user == null)
            {
                Clients.Caller.showErrorMessage("Could not find that user.");
            }
            else
            {
                db.Entry(user)
                    .Collection(u => u.Connections)
                    .Query()
                    .Where(c => c.Connected == true)
                    .Load();

                if (user.Connections == null)
                {
                    Clients.Caller.showErrorMessage("The user is no longer connected.");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var connection in user.Connections)
                    {
                        Clients.Client(connection.ConnectionID)
                            .addChatMessage(name + ": " + message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        using (var db = new UserContext())
        {
            var user = db.Users
                .Include(u => u.Connections)
                .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == name);

            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new User
                {
                    UserName = name,
                    Connections = new List<Connection>()
                };
                db.Users.Add(user);
            }

            user.Connections.Add(new Connection
            {
                ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId,
                UserAgent = Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"],
                Connected = true
            });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        using (var db = new UserContext())
        {
            var connection = db.Connections.Find(Context.ConnectionId);
            connection.Connected = false;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

I want to enhance this method because using this method will create many ConnectionIds that is not needed at all. Also, with this method the Connections table will be enlarged with time without any useful.

Comment: Do you need to maintain multiple connection ids? Do you have a requirement to support for `a single user connected on two or more machines simoulathenously`?

Comment: In my application, the user may use multiple browsers or multiple devices, so I have a requirement to support two or more machines simoulatenously.

Answer (score 2):

What about cleaning up the connectionIds instead of setting the Connected property to false? Your OnDisconnnected() method could then look something like this:

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    using (var db = new UserContext())
    {
        var connection = db.Connections.Find(Context.ConnectionId);
        db.Connections.Remove(connection);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

This would stop the Connections table from growing infinitely. You could then remove the Connected property altogether and have the existence of a Connection row indicate that a connection is active.

#### Update

Another approach, if you don't want to delete records but re-use the ones already in the database, could look like this:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    using (var db = new UserContext())
    {
        var user = db.Users
            .Include(u => u.Connections)
            .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == name);

        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new User
            {
                UserName = name,
                Connections = new List<Connection>()
            };
            db.Users.Add(user);
        }

        var connection = user.Connections.Where(c => c.Connected == false && UserAgent == Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"]).FirstOrDefault();
        if (connection == null) 
        {
             connection = new Connection();
             connection.UserAgent = Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
             user.Connections.Add(connection);
        }

        connection.ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId;
        connection.Connected = true;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

Is this along the lines of what you had in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I give you +1.  But why you delete records, what is about update the records if it is exist when onConnect fire ?

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. I suggest to delete records to avoid having the table grow indefinitely, as I thought was your requirement. If the record is just updated, the table will continue to grow, as a new unique connectionId is generated each time a browser connects via signalR. `OnConnected()` only fires once for each connection, so there is no need to update anything there as I see it - only need is to add information about the new connection.

Comment: What I mean is that we have two cases in OnConnected event. The first case is when the is no connection for the user in database, in this case we will create new record in database. The second case is when there a connection for the user in database but the value of the Connected is false, so in this case we will update the value of ConnectionID and the value of Connected. I hope this explain what I say in the previous comment.

Comment: I think I understand what you're after. I'm not sure the gain of re-using existing records instead of deleting and creating new ones are that huge, but if you have a high-traffic scenario then maybe it is. I have updated my answer with a re-use implementation of connections which have Connected false. What do you think about that?